# Error while inserting values in to database

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

When I try to put values in to databse, I am getting this error.

> raise TypeError("%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" % (cls.**name**, kwarg))
>   TypeError: Employee() got an unexpected keyword argument 'EmployeeID'

The code is as below:

```
class Employee (models.Model):
    EmployeeID = models.IntegerField
    EmployeeFirstName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    EmployeeLastName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    EmployeeEmail = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    EmployeeMobileNumber = models.IntegerField
    EmployeeHireDate = models.DateField
    EmployeeType = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Comment: Please show your code performing "insertion" and clarify why you tagged both `forms` and `drf`.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `EmployeeID = models.IntegerField()` instead of `EmployeeID = models.IntegerField`.

Comment: same with `EmployeeMobileNumber` and `EmployeeHireDate`. Your fields need to be instances of `Field` not classes.

Comment: Supporting the comment above, look the difference: `ipdb> models.IntegerField` means `<class 'django.db.models.fields.IntegerField'>` (class) and `ipdb> models.IntegerField()` means `<django.db.models.fields.IntegerField>` (instance)